# How to increase static int value in a template class within constructor and destructor functions?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, static, destructor

Let's assume we have a **template** class **ptr**. The constructor function of ptr class can take values of int, double, another handmade structure etc since it is a template class.

I want to see exactly how many times these constructors and destructors are called and **also** the type of the data that it has been called for. Is this possible to see?

Right now I have a static int value in the template class and 2 constructors (1 default constructor) and 1 destructors in which I increase/decrease the value of the static int value.

```
template<class T>
class ptr
{
private:
    T* data;  
public:
    ptr();
    ptr(T* data);
    ~ptr();
    static int number;
};

template<class T>
int ptr<T>::number = 0;
```

*How can I see for which types these constructors and destructor are called?* All I see now the value of the static int, not for which type it is called.

Comment: Each type you use will create a new type.  a `ptr<int>` will be a different class than a `ptr<double>`

Comment: Yes. That is why there are more than 1 static int number for each class, so I want to see, which one I am increasing or decreasing.

Comment: `ptr<T>::number` gives you the number of `T`s inside `ptr`s, provided you counted right. You can check and add that for a bunch of types. If you want the sum of all types you should make a separate variable since there is no way to ask which types a template has been instanced with.

Comment: so it is not possible to see something like this?:
constructor-char: 1 / 
constructor-int: 1 / 
destructor-int: 0 / 
destructor-char: 0

Comment: It is. Just write `cout << "constructor-char: " << ptr<char>::number << "constructor-int: " << ptr<int>::number;`. You need to write that for each type you are interested in.

Comment: I don't know the type that is the problem. I just increase that static int in constructors and decrease it in destructors. But, there are more than 1 static int value and I want to see their separate values like the static int for char, static int for int, static int for double etc.

Comment: You can use a `map type_occurances<string, int>` and then iterate over `type_occurances` and print them all out. The `int` is the same as `number` and for the string you can use `typeid<T>.name()`. The `name` that `typeid` gives you may not be the name you want and it is compiler dependent.

Comment: cout << "constructor-char: " << ptr<char>::number << "constructor-int: " << ptr<int>::number

I tried this and it works. Thanks. Is there an automatic way to get that <char> and <int> ? Because now, I need to put all the hand made types (struct complex number for instance) into the same header file that includes the template class.

Comment: There is no template solution, but you can request the name of the parameter with `typeid(T).name()` inside the template and save it somewhere together with the count for easy printing. Thats what the `map` from my last comment is for.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see exactly how many times these constructors and destructors are called...

Well that's easy, you store that number in `ptr<T>::number`, so yes, it's possible to see. For example, to see how many times `ptr<Foo>` has been instantiated, use `ptr<Foo>::number`.

> and also the type of the data that it has been called for

It's not possible to get that kind of information from your template. That's essentially asking: what are all instances `ptr` whose constructor has been called?

What you could do, is define a global map of `std::type_index` to `int`. Since that map wouldn't be limited to one template, it could keep track of calls to costructors of any instance of `ptr`.

It might be worth noting that you can only get an implementation defined, mangled, name of the type using `std::type_index`, so if you want a prettier typename, then you'll need some way to map the `std::type_index` to what you want. If you limit the possible types to select few, you could keep your own map of `std::type_index` to `std::string` and use that for printing, or you could use platform specific demangling.

EDIT:
Storing the type - count map in a non-template parent class (in the similar way as Elemental's answer for total count) would probably be more appropriate than storing it globally.

Comment: How is this different from my comments?

Comment: @nwp the main difference is that you forgot to write your answer in the correct box. And also, you suggested string as the map key.

Comment: I am not sure this actually answers the question. I was slowly understanding the question through suggestions and you just copied my suggestion as an answer, which makes me angry. You shouldn't take credit for other people's work.

Comment: nwp; you can write your answer as a separate answer (copy paste) to the question so that i can choose it as the useful answer as i cannot do it now since it is appended to the question.

Comment: @nwp I did not copy anything. I wrote my answer based on the question only (though I did take a glance at yamatos comments since many people forget to put their clarifications to the original question). I feel quite confident that I understood the question, but yamato is free to clarify if I misunderstood.

Comment: @yamato May as well accept this answer, I have nothing to add to it. Sad sad day.

Answer (score 1):

If you do wish to count all instances (independent of type) you might try to give them a common non-templated super class:

```
class uniptr {
  protected:
    static int number;    
}

template<class T>
class ptr: public uniptr
{
private:
    T* data;  
public:
    ptr();
    ptr(T* data);
    ~ptr();
};
```

This seems to do what you want with some reasonable encapsulation. If it's not immediately clear this works because there is only one class uniptr declared (and therefore only one static int) even though there might be multiple versions of ptr used (like`ptr<int>` and `ptr<String>`).